# in Ionic, is a delegate, a service and a controller the same thing?

Tags: angularjs, service, ionic-framework, delegates

It's not clear to me in the Ionic javascript documentation how to define them. The terms are used in different contexts, but they all seem to point to an instance that gets passed to an angular controller. I've included links to some examples of the usage that confuse me. The first two links show term usage for a "Modal". The second two show an interchangeable usage for "Side Menus"

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ionicModal` and `ionicSideMenus` are directives.
`$ionicModal` and `$ionicSideMenuDelegate` are services what you use to control those directive elements.

Controlling `ionicModal` includes creating, opening, closing and destroying it whereas controlling `ionicSideMenu` includes toggling the side menu(s), setting the open ratio, etc.

`$ionicSideMenuDelegate` service will control all `ionicSideMenus`. Since it delegates its events to all the side menus, it makes sense for it to be called a [delegate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(object-oriented_programming)). On the other hand, `$ionicModal` executes its methods on a single instance (itself). Therefore, calling it a deligate would not make as much sense as it does for `$ionicSideMenuDelegate`.

Comment: So is $IonicModal considered a delegate even if it isn't called IonicModalDelegate? I want to make sure I'm labeling the right things as delegates.